# Insert values using stored procedure with dynamic table name

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, dynamic, insert

I have this SQL Stored procedure (i'm modifying it though)

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[spUpdateProfile] 
(
@TableName nvarchar(30),
@First_Name nvarchar(max),
@Middle_Name nvarchar(max),
@Last_Name nvarchar(max),
@Birthday date,
@Address nvarchar(max),
@Websites nvarchar(max),
@Email nvarchar(max),
@Contact_Number nvarchar(max),
@Gender nvarchar(max))
AS

DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQLString = 'TRUNCATE TABLE ' + @TableName                       
EXEC (@SQLString)

DECLARE @SQLString1 NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQLString1= 'INSERT INTO [dbo].[' + @TableName +
'](First_Name,
Middle_Name,
Last_Name,
Birthday,
Address,
Websites,
Email,
Contact_Number,
Gender) VALUES(' + @First_Name + ','
+@Middle_Name + ','
+@Last_Name + ','
+convert(nvarchar(max),@Birthday) + ','
+@Address + ','
+@Websites + ','
+@Email + ','
+@Contact_Number +','
+@Gender +')'
print @SQLString1
EXEC (@SQLString1)
```

Then when I tried putting values...

```
USE [PersonalOrganizerDB]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[spUpdateProfile]
        @TableName = N'User2',
        @First_Name = N'Caress',
        @Middle_Name = N'caress',
        @Last_Name = N'Caress',
        @Birthday = N'02/06/1992',
        @Address = N'asf',
        @Websites = N'asd',
        @Email = N'a@dfsgsd',
        @Contact_Number = N'42',
        @Gender = N'Female'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

I get these errors

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Invalid column name 'Caress'. Msg
>   207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Invalid column name 'caress'. Msg 207,
>   Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Invalid column name 'Caress'. Msg 207, Level
>   16, State 1, Line 1 Invalid column name 'asf'. Msg 207, Level 16,
>   State 1, Line 1 Invalid column name 'asd'. Msg 207, Level 16, State 1,
>   Line 1 Invalid column name 'a@dfsgsd'. Msg 207, Level 16, State 1,
>   Line 1 Invalid column name 'Female'.

When I print my SQLstring, here it is...

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[User2](First_Name,
Middle_Name,
Last_Name,
Birthday,
Address,
Websites,
Email,
Contact_Number,
Gender) VALUES(Caress,caress,Caress,1992-02-06,asf,asd,a@dfsgsd,42,Female)
```

By the way, I am using the stored procedure on a C# web program. I am seeing the same error message when I run my website. I tried inputting values using "Execute stored procedure on MSSQL management server and C# program (through parameters.add....) please help. thanks!

Comment: I think there are comma's missing in query for `string` values.

Comment: @ShahidIqbal where is that part? Kindly tell me where it is. You may see the content of SQLString1 there. I used the "print SQLString1" command to verify. I see that there is no comma missing. Please let me know if i miss one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
SET @SQLString1= 'INSERT INTO [dbo].[' + @TableName +
    '](First_Name,
    Middle_Name,
    Last_Name,
    Birthday,
    Address,
    Websites,
    Email,
    Contact_Number,
    Gender) VALUES(''' + @First_Name + ''','''
    +@Middle_Name + ''','''
    +@Last_Name + ''','''
    +convert(nvarchar(max),@Birthday) + ''','''
    +@Address + ''','''
    +@Websites + ''','''
    +@Email + ''','''
    +@Contact_Number +''','''
    +@Gender +''')'
    print @SQLString1
    EXEC (@SQLString1)
```

Comment: That is great! I am so very grateful :D hahahaa! thank you very much!